# Error in formsubmit: Activation link keeps sending after activated

Tags: form-submit

I'm currently working with formsubmit to try to make a contact form on my website.

I've watched some videos and read some documentation about it, and I know how to make the form work.

But the problem is, a few hours/days later that I activate the form on the confirmation link at my email adress, it sends the same message every time: "This form needs Activation. We've sent you an email containing an 'Activate Form' link. Just click it and your form will be activated!"

The weird thing is that I've already activated the form, and it was working.

Anybody knows if this is a common error on the website? How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I made some changes and so far it works fine.

Inside the validation email, formsubmit.co sends you a random string
Like this:

> c277d8d5f1ett209149848e390b9b5cc

This is your hidden email, so you must change it on your form:

```
<form 
     method="post"          
     action="https://formsubmit.co/c277d8d5f1ett209149848e390b9b5cc">
</form>
```

It is also very important to check that you have all the name attributes on your inputs.

For me the most important thing is to use the String send instead of the email address

I hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had the Activation message in the spam folder.
I hope it helps you

Comment: Reread the question. They’re not asking why they never received the message.